# pgfplots' Default Cycle List Color Definitions

Tags: pgfplots, color, bar-chart

When creating a (bar) plot in `pgfplots`, tex uses a default list of colors.  What are the definitions of these colors?

Comment: The default `bar cycle list` can (also) be found in the [PGFPlots manual section 4.5.4 on page 85 (in v1.18.1)](https://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=85).

Comment: Note the default `bar cycle list` shown in pgfplots manual is a bit outdated: it actually has six entries (see the answer below), but had only four in the manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pgfplots`'s default color cycle list is available in the [pgfplots source code](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/blob/d8e70d407d4f40a02cfdcc4783e7ff3028d8c5c6/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.code.tex#L3369)

```
/pgfplots/bar cycle list/.style={/pgfplots/cycle list={%
    {blue,fill=blue!30!white,mark=none},%
    {red,fill=red!30!white,mark=none},%
    {brown!60!black,fill=brown!30!white,mark=none},%
    {black,fill=gray,mark=none},%
    {violet!80!black,fill=violet,mark=none},%
    {green,fill=green!80!black,mark=none}%
    }
},
```

Comment: These are LaTeX commands. To communicate with the rest of the (larger) world, for example a printing press, you must use the numerical values of a color mode.