# Code for color in histogram

Tags: pgfplots, color, bar-chart

I would like to know the color codes that appear in the following histogram (code + image):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{
Category 1,6,0,0
Category 2,2,2,0
Category 3,3.5,2.5,4
}\data

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
    create col/expr={
        \thisrow{1} + \thisrow{2} + \thisrow{3}
    }
]{sum}{\data}

\pgfplotsset{
    percentage plot/.style={
        point meta=explicit,
    every node near coord/.append style={
        align=center,
        text width=1cm
    },
        nodes near coords={
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\iszero{\originalvalue==0}
        \ifnum\iszero=0
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\originalvalue}$\,\%$\\ \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=1]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
        \fi},
    nodes near coords align=vertical,
        yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=100,
        enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.18},
    visualization depends on={y \as \originalvalue}
    },
    percentage series/.style={
        table/y expr=\thisrow{#1}/\thisrow{sum}*100,table/meta=#1
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis on top,
    width=10cm,
    percentage plot,ybar,bar width=0.75cm,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    symbolic x coords={Category 1,Category 2,Category 3},
    xtick=data
]
\addplot table [percentage series=1] {\data};
\addplot table [percentage series=2] {\data};
\addplot table [percentage series=3] {\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried, for example, the following histogram with the color blue, but I didn't get the same color:

```
 \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
    ymin=0, ymax=25,
    xmin=-5.3, xmax=80,
    xtick={0, 10, 25, 35, 45, 55, 70},
    ytick={0, 5, ..., 30},
    enlargelimits=0, 
    area style,
    every node near coord/.append style={
        anchor=north,
        },
  ]
\addplot[ybar interval,fill=blue!30,draw=blue] coordinates{(0,16.33)(10,20.57)};
\addplot[ybar interval,fill=blue!30,draw=blue] coordinates{(10,20.57)(25,19.58)};
\addplot[ybar interval,fill=blue!30,draw=blue] coordinates{(25,19.58)(35,17.78)};
\addplot[ybar interval,fill=blue!30,draw=blue] coordinates{(35,17.78)(45,11.97)};
\addplot[ybar interval,fill=blue!30,draw=blue] coordinates{(45,11.97)(55,13.77)};
\addplot[ybar interval,fill=blue!30,draw=blue] coordinates{(55,13.77)(70,13.77)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thank you so much

Comment: As mentioned in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618293/pgfplots-default-cycle-list-color-definitions, the colours you've used in the second snippet are the default colours, and I do get the same blue colour in both cases. If you add the second snippet in your first document, do you get different blues? What does it look like for you?

Answer (score 1):

The colors are

```
\definecolor{newblue}{rgb}{0.70,0.70,1.00} % with  border blue
\definecolor{newred}{rgb}{1.00,0.70,0.70} % with border red
\definecolor{newbrown}{rgb}{0.925,0.850,0.775} % with border newbrownborder
\definecolor{newbrownborder}{rgb}{0.45,0.30,0.15}
```

They were read directly from the `.pdf` file using Inkscape (free). Illustrator or Adobe Acrobat can also be used. In this case, it is possible to find them in the source code, but this is not always the case. You can get the file without knowing how it was generated or the source might be unavailable.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\definecolor{newblue}{rgb}{0.70,0.70,1.00} % with  border blue
\definecolor{newred}{rgb}{1.00,0.70,0.70} % with border red
\definecolor{newbrown}{rgb}{0.925,0.850,0.775} % with border newbrownborder
\definecolor{newbrownborder}{rgb}{0.45,0.30,0.15}

\begin{document}
    
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{
        Category 1,6,0,0
        Category 2,2,2,0
        Category 3,3.5,2.5,4
    }\data
    
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
    create col/expr={
        \thisrow{1} + \thisrow{2} + \thisrow{3}
    }
    ]{sum}{\data}
    
    \pgfplotsset{
        percentage plot/.style={
            point meta=explicit,
            every node near coord/.append style={
                align=center,
                text width=1cm
            },
            nodes near coords={
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\iszero{\originalvalue==0}
                \ifnum\iszero=0
                \pgfmathprintnumber{\originalvalue}$\,\%$\\ \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=1]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
                \fi},
            nodes near coords align=vertical,
            yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=100,
            enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.18},
            visualization depends on={y \as \originalvalue}
        },
        percentage series/.style={
            table/y expr=\thisrow{#1}/\thisrow{sum}*100,table/meta=#1
        }
    }
    
\noindent   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis on top,
            width=10cm,
            percentage plot,ybar,bar width=0.75cm,
            enlarge x limits=0.25,
            symbolic x coords={Category 1,Category 2,Category 3},
            xtick=data
            ]
            \addplot table [percentage series=1] {\data};
            \addplot table [percentage series=2] {\data};
            \addplot table [percentage series=3] {\data};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymin=0, ymax=25,
            xmin=-5.3, xmax=80,
            xtick={0, 10, 25, 35, 45, 55, 70},
            ytick={0, 5, ..., 30},
            enlargelimits=0, 
            area style,
            every node near coord/.append style={
                anchor=north,
            },
            ]
            \addplot[ybar interval,fill=newblue,draw=blue] coordinates{(0,16.33)(10,20.57)};
            \addplot[ybar interval,fill=newblue,draw=blue] coordinates{(15,20.57)(25,19.58)};
            \addplot[ybar interval,fill=newred,draw=red] coordinates{(26,19.58)(36,17.78)};
            \addplot[ybar interval,fill=newblue,draw=blue] coordinates{(40,17.78)(50,11.97)};
            \addplot[ybar interval,fill=newred,draw=red] coordinates{(51,11.97)(61,13.77)};
            \addplot[ybar interval,fill=newbrown,draw=newbrownborder] coordinates{(62,13.77)(72,13.77)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The colors can be directly read from source code, see the link in [@TorbjørnT's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624665/code-for-color-in-histogram#comment1559330_624665). Thus no need to read them from Illustrator.

Comment: @muzimuzhi Z  These are LaTeX commands. To communicate with the rest of the (larger) world, for example a printing press, you must use the numerical values of a color mode.